# Entropy of Inverse-Wishart distribution

Tags: entropy, wishart-distribution

What is the entropy of the [Inverse-Wishart distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution)?  I need just a reference, but derivation (e.g. using inverse property) would be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Wishart and Inverse Wishart Distributions

The Wishart and inverse Wishart distributions are arguably the most popular distributions for modeling random positive definite matrices. Moreover, if a random variable has a Gaussian distribution, then its sample covariance is drawn from a Wishart distribution. The relative entropy between Wishart distributions may be a useful way to measure the dissimilarity between collections of covariance matrices or Gram (inner product) matrices.

A new [Bayesian entropy estimator](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224324812_Bayesian_Estimation_of_the_Entropy_of_the_Multivariate_Gaussian) is proposed using an inverted Wishart distribution and a data-dependent prior that handles the small-sample case.

#### [Inverse Wishart Differential Entropy and Relative Entropy](https://www.mdpi.com/1099-4300/12/4/818/htm#:~:text=Inverse%20Wishart%20Differential%20Entropy%20and,d%20as%20per%20(2).)

The above link explains the derivation of the entropy of Inverse-Wishart distribution